# Is it legal to upload a paper to arXiv when it is under double blind review for one of the IEEE journals?

Tags: journals, peer-review, arxiv, preprint, ieee

Is it legal to upload a paper to arXiv when it is under **double blind review** for one of the IEEE journals? I am suspicious that it may violate the double blind review requirements and I couldn't find any thing in the journal's homepage specific to this issue. In general IEEE allows preprint versions to be uploaded to arXiv.

Comment: Why don't you ask the editor?  That seems like the easiest way to get a definitive answer.

Comment: Yes you are right :) sorry for asking here !! I sent a mail to the editor regarding the question. When I receive the answer I will post it here.

Comment: Great, posting it here is a reasonable way to record the knowledge for others who may wonder.

Comment: I dont know whether it is reliable or not RoMEO is a useful service shows whether **preprints** can be uploaded to public domain or not.  http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/

Comment: "Legal" is not the word you want here. Governments don't care. The *journal* might care. Your peers might care. But the law doesn't give a (*&%#*.

Comment: Copy Right issues are in the scope of courts and there is a contract you sign please be aware of your legal activities.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I have just received an email from the editor and I am writing it here

Dear Dr. * * *,

We cannot prevent an author to upload her/his paper to Arxiv. However, because of the double-blind process applied in Communication Letters, we don’t encourage it.
There is only one restriction: Your paper should stand alone without any supplementary material and/or reference to an ArXiv post.

Sincerely,

Comment: Hence it seems to be it is legal, however you shouldn't provide any clue about the arXiv link in the submitted paper.

Comment: I got positive reply from the editor about uploading to arxiv since IEEE has sherpa-Green policy, however I didnt upload to arxiv. While thinking the process I decided not to put the double blind review process at risk.

Answer (score 9):

You mix two things, especially in the comments to the answer by **jwenting**:

1. *Fair review process,* which in the journal you chose means double-blind review.
2. *Free access to information*, which in your opinion seems to mean that the article should be open-access.

While the second can be true, it cannot mean you break the first one. So: It's quite wrong to pre-publish an article if it's under a double-blind review. At least unless you have a permission from the Editor to do so. Once it's accepted, it's just between you and the copyright transfer rules of the journal.

Since IMHO violating a contact is basically illegal, my opinion is that pre-publishing it is very likely both illegal and nonethical.

Comment: http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/rights/rights_policies.html

Comment: It basically says, when you submit your paper to IEEE non-open access journals you have right to publish **preprint** version on third party trusted print servers (not the final version). IEEE currently has just arXiv for trusted third party print servers. So you can do both at last :) it should be like this definitely.

Comment: Well, it just means that IEEE specifically allows you to do so, no matter whether the article will be double-blind reviewed. However, in general, what I said is true.

Comment: IMHO "preprint version" doesn't necessarily mean "while under review": it may just be a term for "your manuscript as opposed to the journal version typeset by the publisher"

Comment: @cbeleites Typically these two things coincide. You put together an article, you publish it as a preprint and you send it to an article. At least around me, people rarely publish preprints in the sense "work in progress"

Answer (score 4):

Even it is legal, is is subverting the process of **double blind** review. I would not do it, but of course, I understand that the advantage it may bring to you may be tempting.

At least in my field it is widespread practice of lab submitting multiple papers to very competitive conferences which take double blind review extremely seriously, and then doing everything they can to actually reveal themselves as the authors (e.g. lab head goes on the "tour" of good universities presenting exactly the same work which is in the review process, hoping that the reviewers of the submitted papers will be in the audience).

I don't like, it is cheating, even if it is nominally legal.

Answer (score 3):

Legal? Sure. There's no law against it.
Contract violation? Possibly, ask the editor.
Ethical? Something else entirely. Quite possibly not.

Comment: I am asking it, since it is **double blind** review. Actually, you give clue about the identities of the authors.

Comment: @fermat4214 so ask the publisher. And hence also the hint that it might not be ethical.

Comment: I asked and waiting for the answer, when I get the answer I will also post it here. By the way for ethical part I want to say something; It is definitely ethical, actually opposing information dissemination is non-ethical, information belongs to humankind and luckily society is becoming more open. Therefore, just considering the legality while IEEE allows pre-print versions to be uploaded to arXiv (which is just an e-print server not a journal).

Comment: @fermat4214 breaking the double blind criteria is the potentially unethical part, as it can violate the independence and impartiality of the reviewers.

Comment: However, there's a law that says you shouldn't violate a contract, so IMHO that is illegal (but I'm not a lawyer and I think that distinguishing such details here doesn't have a true point).

Comment: @tohecz Torts are not illegal, they are torts. The government adjudicates and enforces judgement but is not the complaintant. The law doesn't say that you should not violate contract, it says that if you do then the harmed person has a legal process to obtain compensation from you. Many people--including me--think that you shouldn't violate contracts even when it is to your advantage, but that is a moral rather than legal supposition.

Answer (score 2):

As jwenting points out, there is nothing illegal in doing this. Further, since you don't really have much of a contract (yet) with the journal, there are few possible negative outcomes from this - apart from immediate rejection of your submission. Most importantly, though:

- In all situations where you do not know if it's OK to do something with a paper, either before or after publication, **ask the journal first**.

Certainly, do **not** attempt to upload your paper to the arXiv (or similar repository) whilst your paper is under double-blind review (or any type of journal submission, really), without informing the editor. Failing to do this can be interpreted as acting in bad faith and it is likely to set the editors against you from the start.

Having the manuscript freely available (and possibly easily googleable) completely negates the purpose of the double blind review, as it publicly divulges your identity as the author of that manuscript. I would see this as the conflict of two things you want: (1) you want to publish in this highly-respected journal, which at least partly built its reputation through things like double-blind review, and (2) you want your paper available to everyone as soon as possible.

Those two things are incompatible, and you need to choose one of the two. You're not giving away much; you simply need to sit on the paper for maybe a month or two (or however long the review process takes) and you can then upload your eprint. You're not "opposing information dissemination", you're under an embargo of sorts, which is perfectly reasonable and which you're submitting to voluntarily through your choice of journal. (Note, in particular, that public policies that mandate the open access of taxpayer-funded research do not usually require this until six months *after* the publication; they definitely do not apply before it.)

Answer (score 1):

**No**. I checked with the IEEE customer service and they told me one cannot upload a paper to arXiv when it is under double blind review for one of the IEEE journals. See details below if interested.

---

I asked the question to one of the conferences (viz., [ICASSP 2020](https://2020.ieeeicassp.org/)) publishing their proceedings in IEEE and here is the response I received:

> IEEE policy permits authors to post their articles to the preprint 
>   repository arXiv. Posting rules for each stage of the article life
>   cycle  are:
>
> - **Pre-submission**: Before submission to an IEEE publication, the  papers may be posted anywhere, including to arXiv.
> - **Upon acceptance**: Upon  acceptance to an IEEE publication, the arXiv posting must be updated by  replacing the pre-submission version with
>     the accepted version. The  accepted version must have the IEEE
>     copyright line (© 20XX IEEE) but no  other changes may be made. The
>     version suitable for posting is available  on the Completed Articles
>     page of the IEEE Author Gateway: 
>     https://authorgateway.ieee.org/ag/public/landing.jsp.
> - **Upon publication**:  When the article is published, the posted version on arXiv should be  updated with a full citation to the IEEE
>     publication, including DOI. No  other changes may be made.
>
> Visit the IEEE Author Center for more  information on SPS sharing and
>   posting policies at  https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/.

However, that didn't specify whether one can submit a paper to arXiv after the paper submission deadline and before the notification of acceptance (i.e., while the paper is under review). So I emailed authors@ieee.org about it and got the following response:

> Sharing of a submitted paper is allowed under the following circumstances:
>
> - On authors' personal and employers' Web sites
> - On institutional/funder Web sites if required
> - For authors' own classroom use
> - Only on Scholarly Collaboration Networks (SCNs) that are signatories to the International Association of Scientific, Technical, and Medical Publishers' (STM) "Sharing Principles"
>
> For more details, see https://conferences.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/get-published/post-your-paper/. Thank you for publishing with the IEEE.

I then asked whether arXiv counts as a "Scholarly Collaboration Networks (SCNs) that are signatories to the International Association of Scientific, Technical, and Medical Publishers’ Sharing Principles", and I got the following response:

> Thank you for your inquiry. ArXiv does not seem to be included on https://www.howcanishareit.com/ , which is the Web site that lists the permitted SCNs. Some SCNs where the article can be shared are listed there.

That being said, I would advice to double check with each conference you are targeting to make sure that they don't have any extra policy on top of IEEE policies.

FYI:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_academic_journals_by_preprint_policy
- [Why would a conference discourage authors to submit their papers to pre-submissions platforms (e.g., arXiv) before submitting them to the conference?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/88273/452)

Comment: IEEE is in that wiki page and please check the following page https://v2.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/   AND  the following page https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/become-an-ieee-journal-author/publishing-ethics/guidelines-and-policies/post-publication-policies/   THIRD item says  "arXiv.org, TechRxiv.org, or any not-for-profit preprint server approved by the Publication Services and Products Board (PSPB)"   and nothing is mentioned about "double blind" review

Answer (score -4):

Certainly, do not attempt to upload your paper to the arXiv (or similar repository) whilst your paper is under double-blind review (or any type of journal submission, really), without informing the editor.

I definitely **do not** recommend to do it. First, an Editor, of course, will say no as he must follow the review policy. Secondly, if your paper is indeed of high quality, there is always a risk that your idea could be leaked (it is normal that people communicate with each other about topic in your paper). If you decide to submit to arXiv, you should follow the rule “don’t ask, don’t tell”. So, you should never ask Editor anything about arXiv, and the Editor, who understands this problem, would not say you anything about arXiv. It is a normal practise now when the paper goes to journal and to arXiv at the same time.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back up your claims? The accepted answer clearly contradicts that the editor will say no. If you have evidence of leaking of ArXiv papers, take a look at [this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/17145/7734). Why should adhere to a general ”don’t ask, don’t say” regarding the ArXiv with editors? Remember that journals could ban preprints entirely, if they were against it – and the editors can even care less, as they are usually not paid by the journal. In fact, many journals allow submitting papers directly from ArXiv.

Comment: I did not say anything about leaking from arxiv. I imply that if you submit a high quality manuscript in a journal you should upload your submission to arxiv as well to prevent a leakage of your idea. This is exactly what I said. What I recommended is to submit the manuscript to a journal and to arxiv at the same time, and follow the principle 'don't ask, don't tell'. Evidences of leakage? Please read what Grisha Perelman, who refused to take prestigious Fields Medal and million dollars premium, wrote about plagiarism in science.

Comment: ”I did not say anything about leaking from arxiv.” – at least that’s the obvious way to interpret your loosely connected sentences. Also, “do not attempt to upload your paper to the arXiv … whilst your paper is under double-blind review …, without informing the editor.” is almost the opposite of “What I recommended is to submit the manuscript to a journal and to arxiv at the same time, and follow the principle 'don't ask, don't tell'.” Finally, can you link or cite Perelman? He did not exactly write much in the last years, IIRC.

Comment: I gave the comment to the sentence: "Certainly, do not attempt to upload your paper to the arXiv ...". This sentence is just copy/paste from this blog. Here is the link about Perelman: http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2006/08/28/manifold-destiny

Comment: If you want to comment on that sentence, make clear that it is a quote, e.g. by prepending `>`. Also you should have made clear better what pronouns in your sentences are referring to and somewhat relate your sentences to something. Finally, Perelman does not say, let alone write anything about plagiarism in that article (the term is only mentioned in the context of Yau’s accusations of plagiarism against Tian) while any quote from Perelman is very unspecific.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion about how to comment in this blog. As for Yau, here is what Grisha Perelman said: “I can’t say I’m outraged. Other people do worse. Of course, there are many mathematicians who are more or less honest. But almost all of them are conformists. They are more or less honest, but they tolerate those who are not honest". There is a book about Perelman "Perfect Rigor: A Genius and the Mathematical Breakthrough of the Century". I think this should be enough to understand about plagiarism and how serious it may be in modern science.

Comment: Therefore I always suggest, if you have a high quality manuscript go ahead to a journal together with arXiv. Fortunately, majority of Editors are fair enough and would not tell you anything, but you also should not ask. Just be reasonable!

Comment: By the way Editor said Yes (since IEEE is supporting sherpa-Green policy) as you may see from the top answer, but I didnt upload to Arxiv to not to put the double blind review process at risk.

Answer (score -4):

I have many publications in peer review journals. Let me share my experience. If you have a high quality manuscript, I recommend you to submit the manuscript to a journal and also to upload it to arxiv. Do not ask Editor anything about arxiv as it is completely counterproductive. If due to some reasons your manuscript is rejected from the journal, you will save your idea in arxiv at least. Further you can refer to your arxiv paper for future peer review journal publications.

Comment: The question is whether this is *allowed* in a double blind review scenario. This does not seem to answer that question.

Comment: The question was not whether this is allowed. The question is if you should you ask Editor about arxiv.

Comment: I don't see anything about asking an editor in the question. The question is, "Is it legal to upload a paper to arXiv when it is under double blind review for one of the IEEE journals?"

Comment: Agree. But this is just a title. The core of the problem is if you should ask an Editor about upload to arxiv. My opinion (and experience) - no, you should not.

Comment: Double blind review is an important point here, since you make your identity open while the review process wants the opposite (also you cannot say "in our previous work [x] we got blah blah blah" since you make your identity open while writing Author 1 and Author 2 in the title page)