# What is arXiv.org for? Should I upload my unpublished, but submitted manuscripts there?

Tags: paper-submission, arxiv, preprint, online-publication

I know arXiv.org for several years (3 to 4 years), and have used it to access extended versions of conference papers, corrected versions of published papers in a peer-reviewed journal and also search it to find whether my idea about a topic is new or not.

However, I have written several manuscript in the last two years and today, one of my friends offered me to upload my manuscripts to arXiv.org before publication, so others won't spend their time reinventing what I've done.

I have asked my supervisor, but he prohibited me from doing so, because of possible abuses might be caused by cheaters, e.g. using my work to publish somewhere else or stealing my ideas without citation. Also, he told me about the copyright forms we have signed which transfers the right of publication to the journals.

To this end, I have googled for an hour, however as time passed I found less and now I am totally confused! What should I do? What is arXiv.org for? Is it legal to upload a published paper there? Is it illegal or does it have a bad impact on the referee and the editors to see a submitted manuscript online at arXiv?

Sorry for the long text.
Regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why upload to academic preprint sites like arXiv?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16832/why-upload-to-academic-preprint-sites-like-arxiv) and also [Plagiarism and the ArXiv (or other preprint servers)](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17145/plagiarism-and-the-arxiv-or-other-preprint-servers)

Comment: So, I shall just talk again to my supervisor on this. Thanks @jakebeal . Now that I have clicked on the button "I've got my answer", what should I do to this question? Shall I delete it? or edit it adding that the answer is there...

Comment: Glad that it was helpful to you!  You now don't need to do anything: duplicates are fine to leave around, because they can help people find the answer they are looking for.