# Can i put the submitted paper in the arxiv?

Tags: publications, conference, paper-submission, arxiv

I'm not so familiar about the regulations regarding arxiv and conference papers.

Recently i submitted a conference paper and it's under review, but i couldn't put all the supplementary materials (proofs and extra analysis, pseudo-code etc) in the submitted paper due to the limited space!

So legally can i put the complete version in arxive, hoping if the reviewer search for the related works he might notice the complete version by chance. Then he can benefit from the extra supplementary materials provided there to better understand the submitted version?

Also arxiv is like putting the paper there, or you also need to wait for the acceptance from arxiv?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have just submitted the paper, chances are you haven't given the rights over to the committee. As long as you haven't agreed to some terms and conditions that gives temporary ownership to the conference, then you should still have ownership of the paper and can do what you want with it.

If you want to be doubly sure, a short email to the conference proceedings editor can erase any doubt you may have.

Comment: They have that in their submission page: "Papers submitted to this conference must not have been accepted or be under review by another conference with a published proceedings or by a journal". Would it include arxiv?  About the conference chairs, I think they are not so communicative based on my prior experience!!

Comment: I agree with the conclusion (namely, you can probably do it, but could write to the program committee to find out for sure).  However, I don't agree with the reasoning that it's OK because you haven't given ownership to the conference yet.  It's true that this means it's not a copyright violation right now, but it's not necessarily compatible with publishing in the conference (it would prevent you from signing the publishing agreement when your paper is accepted if they want exclusive rights).  In practice this is not likely to be a problem, but it depends on knowing the conference's policies.

Comment: @Bob: For a SIAM conference it should be fine.

Comment: When the conference paper is accepted, you should make a note of that in the arXiv. If it's just submitted, you don't need to mention it (after all, it could be rejected).

Answer (score 4):

In the fields I work in (pure math and theoretical CS), it is completely standard.  Most conferences/journals have clear policies on what kinds of publication elsewhere are acceptable, which (a) generally do not allow submissions that have been previously submitted or published in other *comparable peer-reviewed venues*, but (b) often explicitly clarify that **preprint servers (e.g. arXiv) and authors’ homepages are not included in that prohibition,** since they’re not peer-reviewed venues.

So: it is almost certainly OK — but you can probably set your mind at rest by looking up (or asking about) the journal/conference’s policies on submission/publication elsewhere.

Comment: I did, they said it's ok! BTW, if i get rejected, and someone else uses my work and publish it before i do, then i'd loose my chance to publish my work?

Comment: Glad to hear they confirmed it’s OK!  At least in my field, you certainly wouldn’t lose the chance to publish your work — if you get rejected from one journal or conference, you can then submit to another, regardless of whether you or anyone else has made further progress in that direction in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I put the submitted paper to arXiv?

That depends on the conference/journal policy: check with them. Sometimes the author instructions on the conference/journal website might mention the policy.

For example, [ICASSP 2020](https://2020.ieeeicassp.org/) is [ok](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/134825/452) if you upload to arXiv your submitted paper, but [ACL 2019](http://www.acl2019.org/EN/index.xhtml) is not ok (doing so will result in your paper being rejected).